# How to send an image from one page to another page using PHP

Tags: php, image, photo, photos

I have a project am working on,, its about (Graphical Password) it's an authentication security system (Web Based), which ask the user to register by entering his information such as (first name.. last name.. etc ) and with these information there will be a group of images with each image has a number written below it ,, so the user will enter his info like usually and will be an extra field for (image number) the user write the number of the image that he want ,,(the images will be previewed as thumbnails in the page). at the end he click submit, the information it will be stored in database using (PHPMyAdmin),in the database there will be columns for each data plus a column for image number, it will be storing the image number ONLY not the images, the images stored in a folder with its names from (1-20), till here no problem..

***The Problem is :*** When the user click submit it should open another page and it should display the image that he chosen before from the previews page with big size image so later i can do some processing on the image..

**My Question is :** How to send that image to another page by using PHP language..

Am using DreamWeaver CS6, here is a photo of the site http://www.4shared.com/photo/YcBeAhsz/Capture.html?

and the code is here : http://www.4shared.com/file/unOI9Ejs/registeration_page.html?

I hope my question is clear and i wish i can get some answers.. thanks in advance..

Comment: When you said "it should open another page", do you mean that it opens a new window? Or do you mean that the user gets navigated to another page (i.e. normal form submission)?

Comment: i meant it will navigated to another page..

Comment: Well, you should be able to get the number they enter with `$_POST['some_input_name']`, no?

Comment: get the number they entered from a different page ?

Comment: Do you mean another page on the same site ??? or the next page on the same site

Comment: basically i have 2 separate pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky without know the code your using.

You can store the images you get to the web server by:

```
file_put_contents('image1.gif',file_get_contents('http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif'));
```

The on the next page display the image back.

```
<?php
$user_picked_img_id = 1;
?>

<img src="image<?php echo $user_picked_img_id ?>.gif"/>
```

Let me know if that fits what you are trying to do.

Comment: here is my code,, http://www.4shared.com/file/unOI9Ejs/registeration_page.html?              Please i feel am lost ,, i really appreciated your help, thanks aloott

Comment: i think i need to do something with the Submit bottom, something like linking it to another page by sending the number of image that inserted in the field of image number, and then in the second page receive the image..

Comment: Looks like your Images are already local. In this case you do not need to save the image so you can skip that part. Just save the Image_number to the user session. session_start(); $_SESSION['image_number']=$_POST['image_number']; then when you render the HTML add in the id. <img src="images/<?php echo $_SESSION['image_number'] ?>.jpg"  width="150" height="150"> That should work.

Comment: i have another problem which it seems to me confusing ,, when click the submit bottom its only add the data to the database but it does not navigate to the next page with is stored locally ,, i use the code <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"
     onClick="window.open(registeration_page2.php)">                   it should open i think but it doesn't i don't know where is the mistake ..

Comment: i know the submit bottom has a value="submit" but does this prevent onClick from working >?? if this the case then what is the alternative ?

Comment: You would what to submit the form  normally, then redirect or just show page two.